# How to set ExecStart from function output in systemd config file?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, systemd

I created a `systemd` service file in directory `/lib/systemd/system/` to launch `nodejs` as a service. The problem is that the file contains hardcoded path to `nodej` in `ExecStart` field. It means that any time I update `nodejs` I will have to manually change this service file. Is there a way to use `which node` command in the file below to automatically set the path?

```
[Unit]
Description=node-server-1
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment=NODE_PORT=3001
Type=simple
User=manid
ExecStart=/home/manidos/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/bin/node /home/manidos/node-nginx/index.js
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Write you own script with which node and the node start commands in it and then reference that in the systemd service file.

Comment: you should create a link to the current release and refer it: ln -s /home/manidos/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1 /home/manidos/.nvm/versions/node/current

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a simple bash script within the `ExecStart` line:

`ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '$$(/usr/bin/which node) /home/manidos/node-nginx/index.js'`

Basically, this is running the `which` command in a subshell and passing its stdout to be run by the outer script. Double-dollars are needed to use this particular syntax in a systemd unit file, as documented in the [systemd.service manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html).